# Subtle difference between Fortran and c with respect to how sources are interfaced and compiled together

Tags: c, interface, module, fortran, header-files

Both languages have a way for a single program/library to span over multiple files. C languages use include statements using explicitly created header files, whereas Fortran has the compiler generate an interface from a single module. Forgive me in advance if I misunderstood how either language compiles its source code.

In c/c++ programs you usually create .c files containing source code, and .h files containing the interface to your code so that other source files can anticipate what is in the source, which is then compiled all together into libraries, object files, etc.

In Fortran programs (90+), you can put code into separate modules, and instead of explicitly writing a header/interface file for each one, the compiler will generate interfaces for them and put them into separate binaries (.mod files) in addition to the compiled object files. Creating libraries, object files, etc then requires you compile/link them together.

Why is there this subtle difference between how these languages compile their interfaces? Is it just a quirk that resulted from the long histories of either language?

Comment: The Fortran standard says nothing about `.mod` files.

Comment: If different languages couldn't use different approaches to accomplish the same things, how many languages would we have?

Comment: Yes, it's mostly an artifact of each language's development history.  And other languages (like, say, Java) do their own thing.  There's no reason to expect two different languages to use the same conventions for compiling and linking code in multiple source files.

Comment: Why do you expect different languages have identical features?

Comment: I don't expect anything from a language @Olaf, I just noticed the difference and wondered if there was a reason behind it. I guess in practice, there are many ways to skin a cat..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is far less organized than you make it sound. The use of "header" files is purely a *convention*; the preprocessor allows arbitrary textual inclusions, and there is no principled division of "interface" and "implementation" built into the language.

The simple fact of the matter is that linking separate translation units of a C program is not checked or "safe"; it's *your* responsibility that the pieces that you link actually fit together.

In early C, function declarations could be implied, and function arguments were not checked at all. So you could stick a call `foo(1, 2, 3)` into your code, and it would imply the declaration of a function `int foo()`, and the arguments would need to match the parameters that the eventual function definition would use.

The two key features in C that make header files useful are *declarations* and *function prototypes*. If you agree to always require an explicit declaration of a function before use (something compilers can warn you about), then you can provide that declaration in a "header file", and there's a better chance that the link fits. Function prototypes are an extension of the concept of declarations that automatically fix up arguments at the call site with the parameters in the function definition, and so if you choose to use all those features, you can reasonably well document your function call interface via header files. But all that is purely convention!

Comment: Actually modern C (since C99) requires function declarations before using them.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, but you could still just perform that declaration locally, like `extern f();`. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nZyH1HxbFhECggel)

Comment: An `extern` declaration is not local actually. Anyway, you are correct a non-prototype declarator is still allowed. It has just be made an obsolescence feature in C11 (not sure if it was in C99 already). IMO another point the commitee was too half-hearted making the language safer. I'd bet they will not remove this legacy of a legacy even from C2x.

Comment: @Olaf: I meant "locally" in the sense of "not using a conventional module interface", or maybe "ad-hoc external linkage". It's a way of programming that is very rapid and easy (= lazy), allows for "rapid prototyping", and it was in fairly wide use in the early days of C. In fact, the evolution of C++ faced serious opposition to making prototypes mandatory.

Comment: I well know this stuff from my first steps in C programming. That was one reason I changed to Modula-2 after first tries (was less of a change as I came originally from Pascal:). It might have been some objection in the early years of C++, but from what I know about C++11 (the second version of the standard) this changed a lot in the past decades. I still miss this clean interface from the Wirth-languages (Oberon-2 has a really nice way to auto-generate the interface)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kerrek, pretty interesting how conventions have developed in parallel with the standards of both of these languages. Looking at modern codes, it's difficult to determine whether something is one or the other.